# Error FASTCGI stderr when call a class in subfolder on Nginx PHP

Tags: php, nginx

I did a php program. My development environment is Windows + IIS + PHP 7.4. In the production server i have  RedHat + Nginx + PHP 7.4.

The issue is: in my development environment all works fine, but in the server I can't instance no one class. I only get a blank screen.

My code in the index.php is:

```
    <?php
        $generalObj = new \controls\General;
        var_dump($generalObj->Test1());
        echo "Works fine";
        exit;
    ?>
```

My folder structure is **/index.php** and **/controls/General.php**. I've reviewed the case sensitive and all is right at this aspect.

My class General.php code is:

```
<?php
namespace controls
{
    class General
    {
        public function Test1() {
            return 'Test OK';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In the Nginx's Log I have the net message:

```
2022/10/20 10:14:00 [error] 2729#2729: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "controls\General" not found in /var/www/html/operations/dispatcher3/index.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/operations/dispatcher3/index.php on line 6" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.0.8, server: _, request: "GET /operations/dispatcher3/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock:", host: "192.168.0.101"
```

Why Nginx does not find the Class if the name, and folder is OK... What you think which can be happen?

Comment: Do you "include" the General.php file? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Hahahaha... Beginner's mistake... Thank you by the support :D

Comment: Welcome :). Going to recommend close as not reproducible by anyone else.